Trying to configure Socialite with SAML2 in Laravel 11
I am trying to follow the instructions from https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/socialite and https://socialiteproviders.com/Saml2/
I have run
composer require laravel/socialite
composer require socialiteproviders/saml2

And my web.php includes
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;

Route::get('/auth/redirect', function () {
    return Socialite::driver('saml2')->redirect();
});

Route::get('/auth/callback', function () {
    $user = Socialite::driver('saml2')->user();
});

But when I go to localhost/auth/redirect I get an error
Driver [saml2] not supported.

Am I missing a step here?

Check if your AppServiceProvider boot method has the required extendSocialite call (described here). You'll need to add use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event; in the file so the call works.
After that, check the saml2 configuration in the config/services.php file.
